# Orderer system channels mapping to same Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to set up two Hyperledger Fabric orderers (with the same genesis block). The block defines the orderer to use Kafka as orderer type, as well as the name of the system channel that each orderer will start.

However, as each channel is mapped to a topic in Kafka, this will mean that both system channels will be writing to the same topic.

What would be the best practice here - to keep it this way, to create different genesis blocks for each orderer, or perhaps some other solution I have not thought of?

Comment: This is probably a better question for the HL mailing list or HL RocketChat.
I'll answer below anyway for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create multiple, fault tolerant ordering service nodes (OSNs) using Kafka, then you need to use the same genesis block for all of the OSNs.

If you are trying to create different ordering services using the same Kafka cluster, I would not do that as you might run into channel naming conflicts across the two different orderers.

Comment: Hello Gari, thanks for your reply. Is it not a "naming conflict" if both OSNs write their system channel events to the same Kafka topic?

Comment: Ah --- so the first OSN to write to the topic will actually create the topic ... and then the other OSNs will just use the existing topic.   And of course for each channel (including the system channel), there is built-in conflict detection to ensure that OSNs cannot clobber updates which were posted to them.